# Shortest Path between capitals passing through other capitals

Tags: java, path, nodes, shortest-path

I am trying to develop some code for a college work and I have an algorithm that gives me the shortest path between two nodes in a graph. Please note that the nodes are Countries that have a capital.

Can anyone explain me how I can develop something that gives me the shortest path from country A to country B passing trough a list of capitals (countries)?

I have implemented a method that gives me the distance between two geographical points as well.

My initial thought was to order the list of capitals based on their distance to the country A and then sum all the distances of the shortest path between country A and the first of the list, then the first of the list and the third of the list and so on. Apparentely this is not correct.

```
    public double shortestPathCapitals2(List<String> capitais, Pais pOrig, Pais pDest) {
    double dist = 0;
    LinkedList<Pais> shortPath = new LinkedList<Pais>();
    LinkedList<String> temp = new LinkedList<>(capitais);

    temp.addFirst(pOrig.getCapital());
    temp.addLast(pDest.getCapital());

    Collections.sort(temp, (c1, c2) -> (int) (distance(pOrig, shortestPathCapitals2(c2)) - distance(pOrig, obterPaisPorCapital(c1))));

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size() - 1; i++) {
        Pais p1 = obterPaisPorCapital(temp.get(i));
        Pais p2 = obterPaisPorCapital(temp.get(i + 1));
        dist += shortestPath(p1, p2, shortPath);
        shortPath.clear();
    }

    return dist;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What research did you do on the problem before starting to write code?

Comment: @ct_ I have a college assignament that tells me to create a graph with countries and borders and then develop this algorithm. They also gave me the algorithm that gives me the sortest path and the distance ran between point A and point B.

Comment: Given that information, what research did you subsequently do?

Comment: I've found out something called the floyd warshall algorithm but with this timeframe i can't elaborate a matrix now and implement this algorithm because I already have things working with graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem description:**

Given a graph with vertices V and edges E.
We want to find a path P between Va and Vb such that:

- the path contains {V0, V1, ..} (some subset of V)
- the sum of weights on edges in P is minimal

**pseudo-code:**

```
function findPath(startVertex, endVertex, verticesToBeVisited, currentPath)

    // check if we have reached the destination
    if startVertex == endVertex:

          /*
           * there are multiple ways of reaching the destination
           * calculate the length of the past (also called the cost)
           * if the cost is lower than the current minimum, store the path
           */
          cost = calculateCost(currentPath)
          if cost  < currentMinCost:
              currentMinCost = cost
              currentMinPath = currentPath            

    else:

        /*
         * if we have not reached the destination
         * we need to try all possible next hops
         * this algorithm uses recursion to do so
         */
        for every vertex Vn that is a neighbour of startVertex:

            /*
             * this check prevents us from going
             * Paris --> Rome --> Paris --> Rome (endlessly)
             */
            if currentPath contains Vn:
                 continue

            // add the next hop to our path
            currentPath += Vn

            // if this vertex needed to be visit, cross it out in the list
            if verticesToBeVisited contains Vn:
                verticesToBeVisited -= Vn

            // recursion
            findPath(Vn, endVertex, verticesToBeVisited, currentPath)

            // clean up
            if verticesToBeVisited contained Vn:
                verticesToBeVisited += Vn

            currentPath -= Vn
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain me what you mean by "contained" in "if verticesToBeVisited contained Vn" and what "continue" means?

Comment: by 'contained' I mean the past tense of 'contains'. Meaning that you need to store whether the verticesToBeVisited contains Vn, and use this boolean variable later. Continue is an actual keyword in most languages. It means 'skip this iteration of the loop'